# Tapku Calendar integration errors

Tags: iphone, xcode, tapku

I am working with a project and in that I want to integrateing a `tapku calendar`. I followed all the steps and integrated the calendar. But unfortunately I am getting the error due to which my build is failing again and again. The error is as below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TKCalendarMonthView", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in habitstatisticsViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `"Build Active Architechtures"` to `YES` and make sure you have `armv6` also within your valid architechtures along with `arm64, armv7 and armv7s.`