# Tapku not integrating

Tags: ios, calendar, tapku

Continuing from this question here
[Tapku Calander integration errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627395/tapku-calander-integration-errors)

I tried the solution and it didn't work. I have the exact same issue as the author of that question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a backup I made of the framework and used that instead. 
Adding -dynamic to the Other Linker Flags, and edited the included project path in Header Search Paths

Answer (score 0):

In the settings, edit the Architectures, choose other and remove anything that is there. Click Add "+" and put in the field: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) This will support all architectures except 64 bit.